# Why is Binary represented as a String?

Tags: java, binary, decimal

So I am quite new to Java and motivated to learn. This question might seem simple but I genuinely don't understand and have searched Google for answers (no luck).

I am converting a decimal into Binary in Java. However, I thought representations of numbers are supposed to be given in data types `int`, `double`, and etc.

The code is as follows :

```
int decimal = 99;
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(decimal);
System.out.println(binary);
```

Why is it `String binary`, should it not be any of the numerical data types?

Comment: i did not understand your question , are you saying why does `Integer.toBinaryString(decimal) ` returns a string representation and not an integer?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Why?

Comment: because if you put binary representation in an int type it will be something else not that same number , it gives you strings so that you can convert it it whatever representation

Answer (score 2):

Internally, all values are stored as binary values. Because it's easier to read, integers are converted into digits for display. Displaying a value as a binary is thus purely a representation issue.

So 99 is internally stored as 01100011. You can display it as a hexadecimal (0x63), a decimal (99), or a binary. But because the numerical value is the same in each case, the only difference is the symbols used to display it, and this symbolic representation is as a String.

Answer (score 1):

The following `int`s are all equal:

```java
int i = 99;
int j = 0o143;
int k = 0x63;
int l = 0b1100011;
```

If you want to *print* them, you have to convert them to a `String` using a utility method of `Integer`, or you use [number formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).